# Find all machines from a particular network that can connect to my server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, ping

A complete noob/novice here so you might have to be a bit patient so this might be a a very simple question

We have a server in a specific network, say, 120.1.2.56 and only certain systems from a different network, say, 134.98.xxx.xxx are allowed to connect to it and remote desktop into it.

Now the question is, if I had to make a list of all the IP addresses from the 134.98.xxx.xxx that can access the said server 120.1.2.56, how would I do that?

I thought of pinging every machine in that 134.98.xxx.xxx ip range from the said server (using Angry IP scanner or something similar) but 
1. It feels unnecessarily tedious and time consuming and 
2. Ping is not always two way. X can ping Y, doesn't necessarily mean Y can ping X (right?)

Hoping someone can guide me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are right on the ping discovery, nmap would be perfect for that part. `nmap -n -sP 134.98.0.0/16`.

You can then check if your server have ports open:
`netstat /p tcp /a | findstr 3389 # rdp`
`netstat /p tcp /a | findstr 22 # ssh`

Then for each machine that respond, you will have to check for connectivity to your server.

To ensure they can connect you need to check if they can ping (which should be the case in most scenario when you can ping them too ...)
Then check if they can connect (starting an ssh and exit `ssh -q user@120.1.2.56 exit`)
If you just wanna check if they can remote desktop, i think a simple telnet would be the fastest way to check.

Anyway you need access on every machine to check ... I see no other options ...

Comment: I feared that would be the case but it's pretty much impossible for me to get access to all those machines. I'll just have to ask the people on the other side having the server to find it if they have a firewall blocking/allowing a certain IP range.
Thanks a lot Cyrbil :)